# R get text from pdf and convert it to dataframe/csv

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

After extracting a pdf into R using

```
install.packages("pdftools")
library(pdftools)
download.file("http:xxx.pdf", "1403.2805.pdf", mode = "wb")
txt <- pdf_text("1403.2805.pdf")
```

I can read each page as text using

[image]

I'd like to get these tables into a data frame for analysis in R.
Suggestions?

Comment: There are several packages available for this. Try `tabulizer` or `pdftables`

Comment: Possibly by programming. Plenty of blog examples and a few SO examples on doing this type of thing (I know, I've written a few).

Comment: Can you provid a PDF file for which you want to extract some tables?